# Android cannot capture picture from WebView, view.postDelay not running

Tags: java, android, html, webview, bitmap

I need to do a screenshot from my WebView, or you can say, Convert html to Bitmap.

And I have a trouble with this task. view.postDelayd(new Runnable() { ... don't create a new Thread, where my capture picture is

```
private void Main {
    WebView webView = new WebView(this.context); //init WebView
    saveHtmlImage(webView);  //running method for capture picture
}

private void saveHtmlImage(final WebView webView){
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            view.postDelayed(new Runnable() {  //trouble here
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Picture picture = webView.capturePicture();
                    Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap( picture.getWidth(),
                            picture.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                    Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
                    picture.draw(c);
                }
            }, 100);
        }
    });

    //set HTML code for WebView
    webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, "<TABLE border=\"1\"\n" +
            "          summary=\"This table gives some statistics about fruit\n" +
            "                   flies: average height and weight, and percentage\n" +
            "                   with red eyes (for both males and females).\">\n" +
            "<CAPTION><EM>A test table with merged cells</EM></CAPTION>\n" +
            "<TR><TH rowspan=\"2\"><TH colspan=\"2\">Average\n" +
            "    <TH rowspan=\"2\">Red<BR>eyes\n" +
            "<TR><TH>height<TH>weight\n" +
            "<TR><TH>Males<TD>1.9<TD>0.003<TD>40%\n" +
            "<TR><TH>Females<TD>1.7<TD>0.002<TD>43%\n" +
            "</TABLE>", "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
}
```

When I don't use Runnable, Bitmap.createBitmap(...)  give exception - 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: width and height must be > 0.

When I'm using

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
```

intead

```
view.postDelayd(new Runnable() {
```

the method

```
webView.capturePicture();
```

return empty screenshot, but with correct width and height

Please help me.

Say What I'm doing wrong, or maybe give me another example of code that can convert html code to Bitmap Image.

Thank you in advance for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

Just do a force to fit fullscreen and code a standard screenshot and convert to bitmap. If you need an example let me know.

Comment: I can't do it fullscreen, because I don't use webview in Activity. It's only init like this 

`code`
WebView webView = new WebView(context);
`code`

Comment: Where are you doing this code from then? You are inside your application correct? if you are in your application, then you have a context. If you are in control of adding elements to the screen then you can certainly screenshot them.